# Socket client io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, socket.io-client

I am trying to connect my socket client in spring boot application to my node js socket server. The node js client code is as below.

```
socket = io('localhost:3000', {
      path: 'https://localhost:3000/socket.io',
      auth: {
        token: "abcd",
      },
 });
```

That works fine, the equivalent code in spring boot application is as follow:

```
 IO.Options options = IO.Options.builder()
                     .setAuth(singletonMap("token","abcd"))
                     .build();

 Socket socket = IO.socket(URI.create("https://localhost:3000"), options);

 socket.connect();
```

But I get this error `client io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error` And If I add transport `options.transports = new String[] {WebSocket.NAME }` , I get this error `io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error`. I have aslo checked version's compatibility. https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/installation.html. Socket server 4.x is compatible with client's version 2.1.0.
I'm using socket.io-client dependency as follows.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
        <artifactId>socket.io-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any clues, how to fix this as I have provided the auth parameter as well and everything seems fine.